Help me find the antiderivative of $W(W(x))$ where $W$ denotes the Lambert W Function
Let $W$ denote the Lambert W Function. I must know the antiderivative of $W^2 = W(W(x))$.
I'm already convinced this function is not elementary. This does nothing to settle up my curiosity, as I expect such an antiderivative to be given in terms of $W$, which is itself non-elementary. I cannot rest while there is doubt on the possibility of writing it in terms of any reasonable set of functions including itself and factorials.
I've been researching this for the last couple of weeks, so here is everything maybe useful I've found. Any contribution (or simplification) for this list is welcome.
Identities
From definition we have $W^{n}\exp W^{n} = W^{n-1}$. Therefore

$\exp W^n = \dfrac{W^{n-1}}{W^n}$
$\log W^n = \log W^{n-1}-W^n$

Manipulations

For $x = W^{-1}(u) = ue^u$, we have $\displaystyle \int W^2(x)dx = \int W(u)(1+u)e^udu$.
For $x = W^{-2}(u) = ue^{u(1+e^u)}$, we have $\displaystyle \int W^2(x)dx = \int u(1+u)(1+ue^u)e^{u(2+e^u)}du$.
Aplying integration by parts, we get $$\int W^2 = xW^2-\int\frac1{(1+W)(1+W^2)}$$

Derivatives

$(W^n)' = \dfrac{W^n}{x(1+W)\dots(1+W^n)}$.
In particular, $W' = \dfrac{W}{x(1+W)}$ and $(W^2)' = \dfrac{W^2}{x(1+W)(1+W^2)}$.
$(\exp W^n)' = \dfrac{W^{n-1}}{x(1+W)\dots(1+W^n)}$. In particular $(\exp W^2)' = \dfrac{W}{x(1+W)(1+W^2)} = \dfrac1{(x+e^x)(1+W^2)}$.
$(\log W^n)' = \dfrac1{x(1+W)\dots(1+W^n)}$ and $(x\log W^n)' = \dfrac1{(1+W)\dots(1+W^n)}+\log W^n$.

Combining the previous two expressions we get
$$(\log W^2+\exp W^2)' = \frac1{x(1+W^2)}$$
Integrals

$\displaystyle\int W = x\left(W+\frac1W-1\right)$
$\displaystyle\int \frac Wx = \frac{W\cdot W}2+W$
$\displaystyle\int \frac{W^2}x = \frac{W^2\cdot W^2}2+W^2+W\left(W^2+\frac1{W^2}-1\right) = \left[\left.\int W+\int\frac Wx\right]\right|_{x\leftarrow W}$

Series
$$W(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}x^n$$
$$W^2(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^k n^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\right)x^n$$
Through integration, we get
$$\begin{aligned}
\int W^2
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^k n^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\right)x^{n+1}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n+\frac{(-1)^{n+2}}{n+1}\right)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^k n^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\right)x^{n+1}\\
&= xW^2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+2}}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^k n^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\right)x^{n+1}\\
\end{aligned}$$
This allow us to conclude from a previous step that
$$\int\frac1{(1+W)(1+W^2)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^k n^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\right)x^{n+1}$$

Why? $\qquad \qquad$

What does WolframAlpha say?

I don't think you can do any better than to define $A(x)=\int W[W(x)]dx$ and study the properties of $A(x)$; it is not some known special function.

@user479223 to surpass one's understanding and master the world

@LidingYao WolframAlpha says "no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions"

@CarloBeenakker I understand this is a reasonable guess, but how can I be sure?
